# how to refresh a qwidget for image display?

Tags: qt

I m using widget to display a set of images.each time only one image is displayed..a slider is also attached with this widget as i move the slider another images of set are displayed on widget according to slider value...there is a push button to start the operation of displaying images.
Now my problem is when i click on push button first time.everything works fine but if i click on it second time to display another set of images.it doesn't get updated but if i move the slider it display images correctly even if i  move back the slider it works fine..
so problem is only with the first time display of second set of images..so how to resolve it??

Comment: Did you try to call `QWidget::update()` after changing the images? Please show your code if possible.

Comment: i tried it but not successfull..i also tried setupdatesenabled..nothing is working here..it is only with imagedisplaying..m updating image no n all..all r updating except image..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Use

```
QCoreApplication::processEvents(0);
```

to refresh.